# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context even whilst in object

Tags: php, class, mysqli

I'm getting this error when calling my database class and running a query function.

Here is my class:

```
class dbConnect {

public $mysqli = null;

public function __construct() {
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli( "localhost", "root", "pass", "database" );
    if ($this->mysqli->connect_errno) 
    {
        echo "Error MySQLi: ("&nbsp. $this->mysqli->connect_errno 
        . ") " . $this->mysqli->connect_error;
        exit();
    }
    $this->mysqli->set_charset("utf8"); 
}

public function __destruct() {
    $this->closeDB();
}

public function runQuery($qry) {
    $result = $this->mysqli->query($qry);
    return $result;
}
```

Here is my page:

```
$db = new dbConnect();
$insert = "INSERT INTO `users` (`username`,`password`,`email`,`ip`,`date`) VALUES ('$username','$pw','$email','$ip','$time')";

$db->runQuery( $insert ) or die("Error MySQLi: ("&nbsp. $db->mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $db->mysqli->connect_error);
```

EDIT:

I'm now getting the error     Dbr`0

Answer (score 1):

In the last line in the die you are not in the object.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
$db->runQuery( $insert ) or die("Error MySQLi: ("&nbsp. $this->mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $this->mysqli->connect_error);
```

To this:

```
$db->runQuery( $insert ) or die("Error MySQLi: ("&nbsp. $db->mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $db->mysqli->connect_error);
```

I would, however, recommend you creating a method to fetch the error instead of accessing your database object (`$db->mysqli`) directly.

Comment: Yeah that'st what I normally would do. Even after changing `$this` to `$db` I get the error Dbr`0

Comment: @Sygon That's another issue entirely... We need more information to figure out what is going on, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

In your `or die` statement you forgot a `$this`, replace it with `$db`

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any closeDB function in your class that you called it in the __destruct() function like this: `$this->closeDB();` 
also replace `$this->mysqli->connect_errno` with `$db->mysqli->connect_errno` in your query!

Comment: That function is further on which is `public function CloseDB() { $this->mysqli->close(); }`